# Solution changes when explanatory variables and response variables are rotated in the same way for Linear Regression (Lasso)

Tags: regression, linear-model, lasso

Let's say we have a high dimension linear regression problem: 
$$
y = X\beta + \epsilon
$$
where the dimension of $X$ is $n \times p$, and $y$ is just a $n \times 1$ vector.

We can solve for $\beta$ with standard Lasso.

Empirically, I found that the solution I got from directly solving it is different from solving this following one:
$$
Ry = RX\beta + \epsilon
$$
where $R$ is a $n \times n$ matrix.

And the difference I observed is more than just a result of the choices of $\lambda$ in standard Lasso.

This seems counter-intuitive, could you please help to explain this?

I tried to convince myself with that: the rotation re-weights those samples somehow. For example, after rotation, some values of $y$ get significant larger than its original values, while others remain almost the same. Therefore when Lasso tries to minimize the cost, it learns a different solution. I am not sure if my explanation makes sense, and I hope to hear better ones.

Disclaimer: I am not sure that whether a randomly generated $R$ can cause the solution to change. I guess not. However, I can repeatedly construct several $R$ to make the solution significantly change.

Comment: Lasso introduces $\|\beta\|_1$, the $L_1$ norm of $\beta$, as a penalty. That's not going to be rotation invariant.

Comment: Your "following one" is *not the same model*!  You neglected to apply $R$ to the errors $\epsilon$.

Comment: This might be a case of assuming universal wording, but in a "high dimension linear regression problem", the errors $\epsilon$ are spherically symmetric. Also, while OP hasn't been not totally clear with his wording, the wording seems to (perhaps strongly) suggest that it's being noticed that $\textrm{lasso}_\lambda (X,y) \neq \textrm{lasso}_\lambda (RX, Ry)$, which doesn't directly depend on whether the errors have been rotated. All the same, I definitely should have been more careful before replying!

Comment: @whuber Sorry for the confusion. Will it matter when we solve the problem with Lasso? If it does, the difference I observe in the two solutions seems to be more significant than what can be explained with this.

Comment: @whuber, with more experiment, it looks like your explanation is the most promising one. I didn't realize that in my application domain, the magnitude of $\epsilon$ is actually too big to be just ignored.